# How i can Inject Chart.js class constructor in nuxt 2.15 context as a plugin?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, nuxt.js, dayjs

**Basically I have the following plugin in my project:**

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'

export default (context, inject) => {
    inject('Chart', Chart)
}
```

I used it this way: `new this.$Chart(canvasContext, {...})`

In version 3.9.1 of Chart.js this worked very well, but I need to use the most up-to-date version of it to have access to the Day.js date adapter.

When installing Chart.js 4.3.0 I get this error in the terminal:

```bash
 ERROR  in ./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js                                friendly-errors 10:16:14

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (567:17)                                  friendly-errors 10:16:14
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     };
| class DatasetController {
>  static defaults = {};
|  static datasetElementType = null;
|  static dataElementType = null;
                                                                                friendly-errors 10:16:14
 @ ./node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js 1:0-54 3:0-5 3:18-31 5:0-33 5:0-33 6:15-20
 @ ./plugins/chart.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/eventsource-polyfill/dist/browserify-eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

How can I solve this problem?